# Mongodb find duplicates where second column matches

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to find duplicate documents in my mongodb database , and i have also achieved a portion of it , lets say my document is something like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5900b01b2ce12a2383328e61"),
"Bank Name" : "Seaway Bank and Trust Company",
"City" : "Chicago",
"ST" : "IL",
"CERT" : 19328,
"Acquiring Institution" : "State Bank of Texas",
"Closing Date" : "27-Jan-17",
"Updated Date" : "17-Feb-17"
}
```

and i have written query like this :

```
 db.list.aggregate([
{$group: {
    _id: {CERT: "$CERT"},
    uniqueIds: {$addToSet: "$_id"},
    count: {$sum: 1}
    }
},
{$match: { 
    count: {"$gt": 1}
    }
},
{$sort: {
    count: -1
    }
}
]);
```

so this gives me ids of all the documents where *CERT* is repeating in more than one document which is correct , but in addition to this , i want to add and  where *ST* **not equals to** *IL*. how can i do that .

Please Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add another `$match` with *ST* **not equals to** *IL*, before executing the `$group`, which will ignore the transactions with `"ST" == "IL"`:

**Final Query:**

```
db.list.aggregate([
﻿{
        $match : {
            "ST" : {$ne : "IL"}
        }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id: {CERT: "$CERT"},
        uniqueIds: {$addToSet: "$_id"},
        count: {$sum : 1}
    }
},
{
    $match: { 
        count: {"$gt": 1}
    }
},
{
    $sort: {
        count: -1
    }
}
]);
```

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
 db.list.aggregate([
{$group: {
    _id: {CERT: "$CERT",ST:{$ne:"IL"}},
    uniqueIds: {$addToSet: "$_id"},
    count: {$sum: 1}
    }
},
{$match: { 
    count: {"$gt": 1}
    }
},
{$sort: {
    count: -1
    }
}
]);
```

Let me know if it did not worked or you need some more help

Comment: `$ne` is incorrectly used in `$group` ==> `ST:{$ne:"IL"}`